# Проверка на ввод конкретного типа данных

Tags: c#

Есть метод проверяющий, чтобы пользователь ввёл число только типа int.
Можно ли сделать универсальную функцию на подобие этой, в которую передаётся тип переменной, например в строковом виде ("int", "float", "str" и т.п) и данная функция проверяла на ввод и возвращала указанный тип.

Проблема в том, что не знаю как функция может вернуть универсальный тип данных (int,str,float и т.п), а не только конкретный как в примере ниже.

```
public static int IntGetInput()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input int variable...");
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return input;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        return IntGetInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Так какие все-таки типы нужны? типа "str" нет в C#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Comment: Я бы попробовал через универсальный метод https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-7.0).

```
static T GetInput<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Console.Write($"Input {type.Name} variable: ");
    string? value = Console.ReadLine();
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
}
```

Но он не со всеми типами работает.

```
Console.WriteLine(GetInput<string>());
Console.WriteLine(GetInput<int>());
Console.WriteLine(GetInput<float>());
```

Добавьте обработку исключений, где необходимо.

Comment: У меня аллергия на `ChangeType` :) никогда не угадаешь, сработает он или нет.

Comment: @aepot - с этим согласен. Мне тоже нравится бо́льшая определённость.